# Fatal Error when accessing /index.php/Special:Specialpages MediaWiki page

Tags: mediawiki, fatal-error

I recently upgraded our MediaWiki installation to version 1.24.2

Now when I access the Special pages at http://www.myserver.com/index.php/Special:Specialpages I get this error:

**Warning:** require(/www/local/path/to/web_directory/public_html/includes/specials/SpecialAllPages.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/local/path/to/web_directory/public_html/includes/AutoLoader.php on line 1282

**Fatal error:** require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/www/local/path/to/web_directory/public_html/includes/specials/SpecialAllPages.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /www/local/path/to/web_directory/public_html/includes/AutoLoader.php on line 1282

Can someone please point me at the right direction to solve this problem?

I have already searched the entire interweb for an answer...

PHP version: 5.3.10

MySQL version: 5.5.31

Apache version: 2.2.22

Comment: Well, does the file exist?

Comment: Yes, the file /includes/specials/SpecialAllPages.php.php exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was an error while upgrading/transferring the files to your server.

It seems you solved your problem by yourself, however: You shouldn't update mediawiki's files on top of another version. Instead, you should delete the old installation (keeping the files you need like LocalSettings.php, images/ and so on) and upload a new copy of the new version you want to use. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading for a detailed upgrading tutorial. Following these steps should avoid such problems the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.
I installed v 1.24.2 on top of version 1.21

By some reason the file SpecialAllPages.php was named SpecialAllpages.php with a small 'p'.

After renaming the file to SpecialAllPages.php the same error was triggered regarding the file SpecialAllMessages.php that was named SpecialAllmessages.php

After renaming that file also, everything works fine again.